selecting strikes of options based on close price of index automatically anf get data
Recently trading view provided option charts for indian markets . I some how generated option tickers and got their data i.e close price .Now the question is
if index is trading around 24020,  we should give strike price as input i,e 24000 so that it gets 24000 call and 24000 put strikes close price and plot the sum of their close .
now if i try to round the close price of index to strike price automatically without giving input  , and use that to generate tickers of options ,it is showing error  that rounded close pirce is series string and it should be the simple string .
what will be the solution to this ?

Is this a pinescript code question?
